# How to access an Angular app' s $templateCache from global scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I want to share cached template strings between different js libs and need to call `$templateCache.get("TEMPLATE.HTML")` for an Angular app.
The Angular app is available in public JavaScript scope.

Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any service via `$injector` service:

```
var $templateCache = angular.element(document.documentElement).injector().get('$templateCache');
var html = $templateCache.get("TEMPLATE.HTML");
```

Note: `angular.element` should be provided with element on which angular app is registered. In above example it's `html` tag, and `document.documentElement` points to HTML node.